# Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string

Tags: php, oop

I'm just trying to get the function `something` but I just keep getting the error

> Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string

Any Idea?

```
class A {
    private $a;
    private $b;
    function __construct($a,$b){
        $this->a = ( $a == NULL) ? ' something' : $a;
        $this->b = ( $b == NULL) ? ' something' : $b;
        echo($this->a);
    }
    private function geta(){
        return $this->a;
    }
    private function getb(){
        return $this->b;
    }
    public static function something(){
        echo $this->a;
        echo $this->b;
    }
}
$o = new A('hi','something');
$o->A::something();
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "trying to get"? Can you tell us what output you expect?

Comment: It looks like php translates `$o->A::something()` to `null::something()`, because there is no variable "A" in that object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this please:

```
$o::something();
```

You don't need to reference to `A` because `$o` is already `class A` so you can call directly the static function `something()`

But you are using `$this` inside a `static function` and this is not possible!

So you need to remove the `static` type of the function because inside that function you can't use `$this` 
So you need to make this:

```
public function something(){
    echo $this->a;
    echo $this->b;
}
```

and call it in this way:

```
$o = new A('hi','something');
$o->something();
```

Comment: A static method has no idea of $this, so this may help resolve the method call, but this will then fail as $this is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you’re using does not decompose the way you think it does.

You might think it would do the following: `〈$o->〈A::something〉〉()` (meaning: take the static function `A::something` and apply it on `$o`. However it actually evaluates like this: `〈〈$o->A〉::something〉()` (meaning: it uses `$o->A` as class to call the static
function `something` on).

Specifically:

```
$o->A
```

would read the field (instance variable) `A` from the object `$o`. Since there is no `A` field in the object of class `A`, you’ll get null.

The syntax `$var::func()` (where `$var` in your case is `$o->A`) will try to find the class named by the string in `$var` and call the static method `func` on it (or, if `$o` is an object, it will use the instance’s class). Since `$var` is null in your case, you get the error `Uncaught Error: Class name must be a valid object or a string`.

I think what you meant was to not have `something` be static (since it uses `$this`, which is invalid in a static context):

```
class A {
        private $a;
        private $b;
        function __construct($a,$b){
                $this->a = ( $a == NULL) ? ' something' : $a;
                $this->b = ( $b == NULL) ? ' something' : $b;
                echo($this->a);
        }
        private function geta(){
                return $this->a;
        }
        private function getb(){
                return $this->b;
        }
        public function something(){
                echo $this->a;
                echo $this->b;
        }
}
$o = new A('hi','something');
$o->something();
```

Answer (score 0):

because `Class A` has been called and set for variable `$o` should you using `$o->something()` for call function `something()` of `class A`

but in your code, I see function `something()` is a `static function` and you can't use `$this` for call `non-static variable` in `static function`, if you need using static function, you can refer this example:

```
class A {
    private static $a;
    private static $b;
    function __construct($a,$b){
        static::$a = ( $a == NULL) ? ' something' : $a;
        static::$b = ( $b == NULL) ? ' something' : $b;
        echo(static::$a);
    }
    private function geta(){
        return static::$a;
    }
    private function getb(){
        return static::$b;
    }
    public static function something(){
        echo self::$a;
        echo self::$b;
    }
}
$o = new A('hi','something');
$o->something();
```

if you dont need static function you can remove static of function `something()` and using `$this` for call non-static variable.

Hope help you! sorry for my english. :D